# Reference Request- Summary of Common Loss Functions and their derivatives?

Tags: machine-learning, references, loss-functions

I am creating a summary for my course (and in general for further studies) and I would like to include a part with a general summary over the most common loss functions and their derivatives (if they exist).
I wasn't able to find anything online and most textbooks scatter them throughout so that I am afraid to miss a few.

Any resources you can share are appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for a big list of generic information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good review article for deep learning: [On Loss Functions for Deep Neural Networks in Classification](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.05659) and [Normalized Loss Functions for Deep Learning with Noisy Labels](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v119/ma20c.html).

As deep learning libraries tend to be more modular on this, checking what tensorflow/keras and pytorch supports from their documentation would also help to list loss functions and relevant references they cite.

Comment: Thank you mehmet, these are nice articles, and your latter suggestion is actually super, I think I'll just head over to tf/pytorch and make my own list from there.
cheers!